# Access nested elements in HTMLRewriter - Cloudflare Workers

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I have to access a nested element using [HTMLRewriter](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/html-rewriter) in a Cloudflare worker.

Example

```
<div data-code="ABC">
   <div class="title">Title</div>
   <div class="price">9,99</div>
</div>
<div data-code="XYZ">
   <div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
```

I was thinking about use multiple .on() but the order is not preserved because some .price are missing and I cannot merge correctly results from codeHandler and a PriceHandler

```
await new HTMLRewriter().on("[data-code]", codeHandler)
                        .on(".price", priceHandler)
                        .transform(response).arrayBuffer()
```

I was thinking about iterating new HTMLRewriter() multiple times but the readable stream is locked.

Current code

Worker

```
class codeHandler {
    constructor() {
        this.values = []
    }

    element(element) {
        let data = {
            code: element.getAttribute("data-code"),
            title: element.querySelector(".title").innerText, <--
            price: element.querySelector(".price").innerText, <--- HERE
        }
        this.values.push( data )
    }
}


const url = "https://www.example.com"

async function handleRequest() {

  const response = await fetch(url)

   const codeHandler = new codeHandler()
   await new HTMLRewriter().on("[data-code]", codeHandler).transform(response).arrayBuffer()
    
    
   console.log(codeHandler.values)

    const json = JSON.stringify(codeHandler.values, null, 2)


    return new Response(json, {
        headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
        }
    })  

}

addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  return event.respondWith(handleRequest())
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After quickly looking at the documentation, it seems the [`element` objects in the HTMLRewriter API](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/html-rewriter#element) are currently limited, and can't access children the way that you'd like.

It does seem that the handlers are run in the same order that they appear in the document, which means that for your use case, you can keep track of the current element and add data in that context. You can use different handlers to access the same data by using closures (in this case `values`), like so:

```
addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
});

async function handleRequest(request) {
  var values = [];
  var response = await fetch(request);
  function addToLast(attr, text) {
    var lastIndex = values.length - 1;
    if (lastIndex < 0) {
      // this shouldn't happen, since there should always have been
      // an object created by the parent [data-code] div
      return;
    }
    // need to add them to the previous value, just in case if there
    // are multiple text chunks
    values[lastIndex][attr] = (values[lastIndex][attr] || '') + text;
  }
  await new HTMLRewriter()
    .on("[data-code]", { 
      element(element) { 
        values.push({
          code: element.getAttribute("data-code")
        });
      },
      text(text) {
        addToLast('body', text.text);
      }
    })
    .on("[data-code] .title", {
      text(text) {
        addToLast('title', text.text);
      }
    })
    .on("[data-code] .price", {
      text(text) {
        addToLast('price', text.text);
      }
    })
    .transform(response).arrayBuffer();
  const json = JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)
  return new Response(json, {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    }
  });
}
```

Also note that you can use a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) (e.g. `[data-code] .title`) to ensure that the only `.title` divs that are processed are children of the elements with `[data-code]`.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Do you know how to get element and text at the same time for a selector? It the example it get either text(text) or element(element), not both in the same selector

Comment: You can supply both a text and element function in your handler (though it seems that all the text gets added to the parent). I updated my answer with an example